# Appending values to a dictionary keeps replacing the previous value

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to append values to my dictionary under the key 'UMINV', which it seems to be doing. The problem is, it keeps replacing the values that were previously there.

```py
colpath = '/home/jacob/PHOTOMETRY/RESTFRAME_COLOURS/'    


goodcolindx = {}
colfiledat = {}
colors = {}

for iclust in range(len(clustname)):    

    filepath = catpath + clustname[iclust] + "_totalall_" + extname[iclust] + ".cat"
    photdat[clustname[iclust]] = ascii.read(filepath) 
    filepath = zpath + "compilation_" + clustname[iclust] + ".dat"
    zdat[clustname[iclust]] = ascii.read(filepath)

    colfilepath = colpath + 'RESTFRAME_MASTER_' + clustname[iclust] + '_indivredshifts.cat'

    colfiledat[clustname[iclust]] = ascii.read(colfilepath)  

    goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]] = np.where((colfiledat[clustname[iclust]]['REDSHIFTUSED'] > 0.9) & \
                                              (colfiledat[clustname[iclust]]['REDSHIFTUSED'] < 1.5) & \
                                              (photdat[clustname[iclust]]['totmask'] == 0) & \
                                           (photdat[clustname[iclust]]['K_flag'] == 0) & \
                    ((zdat[clustname[iclust]]['quality'] == 3) | (zdat[clustname[iclust]]['quality'] == 4)))
    goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]] = goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]][0]

    for igood in range(len(goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]])):

        colors['UMINV'] = np.array([])
        print(colfiledat[clustname[iclust]]['UMINV'][goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]][igood]])
        colors['UMINV'] = np.append(colors['UMINV'], colfiledat[clustname[iclust]]['UMINV'][goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]][igood]])
        print(colors)
```

The print statement at the end outputs 1.859, which is the last value in the data set, so it is cycling through them correctly, but it keeps appending over the previous value when I run a debugger. How do I make it so it appends all the values, not just replacing the previous one?

Comment: You need to reduce/modify code to minimum reproducible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only understand maybe 10% of the code you show, but I suspect I know what's wrong with your code.

On each iteration of the last loop, you're clobbering the value of `colors['UMINV']` with this line:

```
colors['UMINV'] = np.array([])
```

When you later append a value to that empty array, it will be the only one. On the next iteration, you reinitialize to an empty array before appending another single value.

I suspect you want the line above to only run once (or maybe once per run of the outer loop, your code is pretty confusing so I'm only guessing at your intentions). That's not hard to fix, just move it up the file, either all the way near the top, just below the dictionary definition, or just above the `for igood in range(...)` line.

I'm also not sure what use that dictionary is, really, if you're not using more than one key in it. Just use a simple variable if you only want one array!

Comment: That worked! thanks! Yeh my code is kind of confusing as this is only the last 50 lines or so, I left out the rest because I didn't think it was necessary.